# How to optimize SEO for landing pages that aggregate business types in a various cities?

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-local-search

If I search for the single word "plumber", Google uses my location and this page "Top 10 Plumbers in Manhattan" from Yelp appears in the results.

https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=plumbing&find_loc=Chicago%2C+IL

They are doing the same for numerous business types and cities. How are they optimizing the SEO to have the correct city page appear for where the searcher is?

I can see nothing in the metadata specifying location or even the business type. Is Google just taking it from the html elements?

To be clear I'm not asking about how to optimize a page for a single local business or even one with multiple locations, this is about landing pages aggregating multiple business listings for multiple cities.

Comment: "Is Google just taking it from the html elements" -- Isn't that how search engines work?  They index the content on  pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yelp and many other directory sites are probably using IP geolocation and then generating a URL based on that location.

When Googlebot requests the site it will get the version based on its IP address, maybe get a city and service page, crawls and indexes the content and other links. Google won't necessarily index a search results page, or any dynamically generated content unless there is a static version of it. Or at least an internal link so that that URL gets crawled. Could be a sitemap.

That is the basic overview, it is slightly more complicated, but that is the basic answer: cache static pages, sitemaps, linking strategy.